# Custom layout in collection view

Tags: uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewlayout

Is possible multiple section in uicollectionview Pinterest Layout. Multiple section is working in the Pinterest Layout class. I have tried this using Pinterest Layout class.  Please help.

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 4
        }else {
            return 20
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your question! please clarify what you are looking for exactly?

Comment: I am using Pinterest Layout class for different item height in collectionview. When i use Pinterest Layout class ,  multiple section is not working. @SuryaKantSharma